# What does an Outpost do in A Dark Room?

Tags: a-dark-room

I was exploring A Dusty Path and I defeating enemies. I found out that once i defeated all enemies in a House (I think) there was an Outpost. What does it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outpost will replenish all water and holds some cured meat. It will be unusable after one use but after you finish an expedition it will be usable again.